# Saving SQL results into a Lst?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

In my database one user can have multiple order. i want to get all orders for a user and save it in a list.

this is what i'm doing now

```
Public Function GetUserOrders(ByVal userID As Integer) As DataSet
        Dim sqlDA As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim myCommand As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("sp_GetUserOrders", myConnection)
        ' Mark the Command as a SPROC
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Dim muserID As New SqlParameter("@userID", SqlDbType.Int)
        muserID.Value = userID
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(muserID)
        Try
            ' Open the connection and execute the Command
            myConnection.Open()
            sqlDA.SelectCommand = myCommand
            sqlDA.Fill(ds)

        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            myConnection.Close()
        End Try

        Return ds
    End Function
```

but i can't seem to figure out how to assign the results to a list.

```
Dim orderList As New ListItemCollection()
orderlist = GetUserOrders()
```

does not work, please help.

Comment: You are trying to cast a `DataSet` to a `ListItemCollection`. That won't work because no cast exists. You need to turn your `DataSet` into a `ListItemCollection` through another method.

Comment: can i set it to an array instead of a list? either one will be fine..

Comment: As I understand it a [`ListItemCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez4tsddk.aspx) is the basis for web UI elements such as drop down boxes. Are you trying to get the data into a web form? If you're not then you should use a generic [`List(of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) where T is the type of data you're storing. How you get the data in there is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it.

i set the list inside the getuserorders function.

```
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        Dim orderList As New ListItemCollection()
        Try
            ' Execute the command
            myConnection.Open()
            dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

            If Not dr.Read() Then
                Return Nothing
            Else
                While dr.Read()
                    orderList .Add(dr("orderCode"))
                End While
            End If
            dr.Close()
        Finally
            myConnection.Close()
        End Try
```